# Graphics3D default properties?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, color, options, lighting

I realized that it is impossible to reproduce default sphere only by declaring its color.

```
In[1]  Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, Boxed -> False]
Out[1] (*a sphere with left upper side orange, right lower side blue*)

In[2]  Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1, 0.8, 0.5, .4], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
Out[2] (*a sphere with overall orange*)
```

[image]

I also tried options like glow, but the result was not successful.

If I say 'I'm busy, just a hamburger please' in a hamburger shop, they will give me a hamburger. But there is a precise recipe for that hamburger.

In this sense, what are all default properties of Graphics3D?
Can I reproduce the default sphere by writing down every property meticulously in a code?

I tried `Options[%]`, just got `{Boxed -> False}`.

Comment: I was going to recommend [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) but it gives `Automatic` for most of its option values. `g = Graphics[...]; AbsoluteOptions[g]`.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ChangeTheLightingOfPlots.html

Comment: Does `Graphics3D[{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, Boxed -> False]` work?